# How I can leave the last web-scraping table?

Tags: python, html, csv, web-scraping

I have got this code, which one i can search the all table called "ctable" on a website with Python 2.7. But i want to leave the last 1-2 table.
How i can do this?

```js
soup = BeautifulSoup(x, 'lxml')

datatable=[]
for ctable in soup.find_all('table',  "ctable" ):

    for record in ctable.find_all('tr'):
        temp_data = []
        for data in record.find_all('td'):
            temp_data.append(data.text.encode('latin-1'))
        datatable.append(temp_data)

output.writerows(datatable)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`soup.find_all('table', "ctable")` is a list (or an iterator), so you can leave the k last elements looping with `soup.find_all('table', "ctable")[:-k]`